Unitary representations of $\mathbb Z^n$ and $\ast$-representations of $C(\mathbb T^n)$
In Vern Paulsen's book on 'Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras, there is a statement written:
There is a one-to-one correspondence between unitary representations $\rho:\mathbb Z^n\rightarrow\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$
and $\ast$-homomorphisms $\phi : C(\mathbb T^n)\rightarrow\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$, given by $\pi(z_j ) = \rho(e_j)$, where $e_j$
is the $n$-tuple that is $1$ in the $j$-th entry and $0$ in the remaining entries and $z_j$ represents the projection function on $j$-th coordinate.
Is it obvious because no argument is provided for this. Clearly a $\ast$-homomorphisms $\phi : C(\mathbb T^n)\rightarrow\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ gives a unitary representation, that is easy to observe. But why the converse?

The statement you cited already provides the argument for the converse. Namely, for any unitary representation $\rho: \mathbb{Z}^n \to B(H)$, you can define a $\ast$-homomorphism $\phi: C(\mathbb{T}^n) \to B(H)$ by $\phi(z_j) = \rho(e_j)$.

$\phi$ gives $\ast$-homomorphism onto all polynomials in $z_1,\dots,z_n$ but why a $\ast$-homomorphism from the space of polynomials be extended to a $\ast$-homomorphism on $C(\mathbb T^n)$? @DavidGao

Polynomials are dense in $C(\mathbb{T}^n)$, so this just follows from the boundedness of $\phi$, which in turn is a consequence of spectral theorem. Alternatively, this definition is not hard to justify from continuous functional calculus.

@DavidGao So, we are using spectral theorem for commuting normal operators here, right? How can we apply continuous functional calculus here directly?

There is a version of continuous functional calculus for commuting normal operators as well, which can be proved via Gelfand duality. The gist is that if you have $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ commuting normal operators and $f$, a continuous function on $\sigma(x_1) \times \cdots \times \sigma(x_2)$ (where $\sigma$ indicates spectra), then you can apply $f$ to the tuple $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$.

Can you provide a reference for this version of continuous functional calculus? @DavidGao
